# add_breadcrumb needs variables in url path, but how?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I've been trying to get my breadcrumb to give me the correct url paths back to parent views. I've tried a number of different variations in my controller, but none of them want to give me the objects variables in the url path

```
add_breadcrumb "Roller Coaster Rules", "/amusement_parks/#{@amusement_park_id}/amusement_park_rules/#{@amusement_park_rule_id}/roller_coaster_rules"
add_breadcrumb "Roller Coaster Rules", "/amusement_parks/" + @amusement_park_id + "/amusement_park_rules/" + @amusement_park_rule_id + "roller_coaster_rules"
add_breadcrumb "Roller Coaster Rules", "/amusement_parks/" + amusement_park_id + "/amusement_park_rules/" + amusement_park_rule_id + "roller_coaster_rules"

add_breadcrumb "Roller Coaster Rules", "/amusement_parks/#{@amusement_park.id}/amusement_park_rules/#{@amusement_park_rule.id}/roller_coaster_rules"
add_breadcrumb "Roller Coaster Rules", "/amusement_parks/" + @amusement_park.id + "/amusement_park_rules/" + @amusement_park_rule.id + "roller_coaster_rules"
add_breadcrumb "Roller Coaster Rules", "/amusement_parks/" + amusement_park.id + "/amusement_park_rules/" + amusement_park_rule.id + "roller_coaster_rules"

add_breadcrumb "Roller Coaster Rules", "/amusement_parks/#{:amusement_park_id}/amusement_park_rules/#{:amusement_park_rule_id}/roller_coaster_rules"
add_breadcrumb "Roller Coaster Rules", "/amusement_parks/" + :amusement_park_id + "/amusement_park_rules/" + :amusement_park_rule_id + "roller_coaster_rules"

add_breadcrumb "Roller Coaster Rules", amusement_parks_amusement_park_id_amusement_park_rules_amusement_park_rule_id_roller_coaster_rules_path
add_breadcrumb "Roller Coaster Rules", amusement_parks_amusement_park_rules_roller_coaster_rules_path
```

I'm trying to get an end result of a link in the breadcrumb similar to [http://localhost:3000/amusement_parks/5/amusement_park_rules/1/roller_coaster_rules/]

What in the hell am I missing?

Ruby 1.8.7, Rails 3.2.12, Debian 5, Twitter Bootstrap, running on Oracle VM

Comment: Are you using `breadcrumbs_on_rails` by any chance? https://github.com/weppos/breadcrumbs_on_rails

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [breadcrumbs_on_rails](https://github.com/weppos/breadcrumbs_on_rails) this may well be of use to you, as it aids the process in creating a breadcrumb navigation menu in your rails application. Below snippets are from the GitHub page:

```
class MyController

  add_breadcrumb "home", :root_path
  add_breadcrumb "my", :my_path
  #call add_breadcrumb to push elem
  #on to the breadcrumb stack
  #takes two arguments

  def index
    # ...

    add_breadcrumb "index", index_path
  end

end
```

**application/layouts.html.erb**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
  <title>untitled</title>
</head>

<body>
  <%= render_breadcrumbs %>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it kind of old question, but on [breadcrumbs_on_rails](https://github.com/weppos/breadcrumbs_on_rails/blob/master/lib/breadcrumbs_on_rails/action_controller.rb) you can write a proc in a name or path 
for example:

```
add_breadcrumb "Roller Coaster Rules", -> (c) { c.amusement_parks_amusement_park_rules_roller_coaster_rules_path(c.params[:amusement_park_id]) }
```

I really recommend you to use [Gretel](https://github.com/lassebunk/gretel), which is way better than breadcrumbs_on_rails for dynamic paths.

> I am developing a gem to automatic convert all breadcrumbs_on_rails
>   definitions(add_breadcrumb) to Gretel´s design, if you want to help me out [BreadcrumbsOnRailsToGretel](https://github.com/victor95pc/breadcrumbs_on_rails_to_gretel)